# Is there a limit to the number of commands a Linux OS can run concurrently?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, operating-system, hardware

I'm a bit short on where and how to ask this question.

I own an application running on Kubernetes that *loves* to shell out and run commands. I did not design this application.

I've found that this application is shelling out and running commands roughly every 30 seconds - and it runs hundreds if not thousands of commands at once. **I've noticed that many commands seem to take a while to begin running (sometimes several hours!), even though executing the command only takes a few seconds.** Why am I seeing this behavior?

How does Linux schedule these thousands of commands to run? Is it limited by CPU logical threads? I know this is a rather broad question with many variables and do not expect an exact answer, but I would like to know if there is something at the OS level or hardware level that is causing these commands to be "queued" before running.

For some specificity: the commands being run are `gcloud` and `kubectl` commands. The commands are being run inside a single container living on its own VM - no other containers that live on this VM are in the practice of shelling out every 30 seconds. The VM has 8 virtual CPUs and 30 GiB of memory, nearly all of which are being used by said container. There are 15 instances of this container running, each on its own VM.

Comment: Spinning up a shell every time you issue a command will impact performance.  There's a lot of initialization.  A given CPU core/thread can run only one process at a time, so the queue is likely to be served very slowly.

Comment: in addition to what @stark mentioned: basically the amount of processes/command that can run in parallel is limited by the number of threads of the cpu where your appliation is running on. if there are more processes spawned the cpu will schedule time slices during which the processes run. it will "fake" concurrency by allocating short amounts of time to each processes, halting it, next process, etc. so if the number of processes is high, due to this scheduling the will take a longer time than when there are less of them running